# New command for text color is not working

Tags: macros

I've been using this newcommand for ages and it always worked perfectly:

```
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\textit{\small\textcolor{red}{ #1}}}
```

However, in my new latex document it returns an error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \comment{ciao}
```

This is the heading I'm using, but I can't find any incompatibility:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,prl,showpacs,superscriptaddress,notitlepage]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.cm,right=1.cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{booktabs}           
\usepackage{amsmath}                
\usepackage{mathtools}              
\usepackage{braket}                 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert} 

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\textit{\small\textcolor{red}{ #1}}}

\newcommand{\oos}{\omega_s}
\newcommand{\ooi}{\omega_i}
\newcommand{\oop}{\omega_p}
\newcommand{\ooa}{\left( \oos,\ooi\right)}

\makeatletter
\let\cat@comma@active\@empty
\makeatother
```

I'd like to ask you if you can see where the problem is!

Thanks

Comment: Your preamble seems to be missing `\usepackage{xcolor}`.  Without it, I get this error: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \small \textcolor 
                             {red}{ ciao}
l.26 \comment{ciao}`.  The problem arises in `\comment` only because it tries to use `\textcolor`, which is unknown without the `color` or `xcolor` package loaded.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should quote the error message precisely, as the console output has a line break at the undefined sequence. But I agree with @StevenB.Segletes that you have just forgotten to load `color` or `xcolor`.

Comment: thank you for your answers, it works now! Apparently, the previous class I've been using so far had a \textcolor function built-in so I didn't have to add the "color" package!

Thank you also for the tip about quoting the whole error, that was my first time in latex section of stackexchange and I thought that the error I quoted was the correct one. I'll be more precise next time!

Comment: @Fraccalo: Most likely the previously used class just loaded `xcolor` or `color` for you, that's why `\textcolor` was working then.